# Creating alert icon with shadow in CSS

Tags: css

i am trying to create the following image using css.... so far i've got this after `googling` a bit http://jsfiddle.net/w9Zgc/ and i want to make the following shape.. [image]

is there any way this can be done... any help would be appreciated.. oh and i would like the shadow to be like the one here... http://jsfiddle.net/w9Zgc/

Comment: for css shapes go [LINK1](http://www.css3shapes.com/),[LINK2](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/)

Comment: box-shadow... http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-shadow.asp

Comment: I had a little go at it and came up with this. Not sure how you would go about putting a shadow on it and so on but still. [Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/4xZ25/)

Comment: check this one [here](http://jsfiddle.net/w9Zgc/62/)

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to create an icon that renders more or less the same in all current browsers. I had to use an extra useless `span`, unfortunately.

http://codepen.io/myajouri/full/nJDzl

The triangle is made of two parts:

- the upper (triangular) part is a transformed (skewed and rotated) square with rounded corners.
- the bottom of the triangle is the bottom part of a rectangle with rounded corners.

Both parts are cut and joint at certain places to form the triangular shape with rounded corners and shadows.